# How To Listen to BLoC Events From Another Screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

**SOLVED: I WAS GETTING ANOTHER STATE INSTEAD OF WHAT I EXPECTED**

I have two screens in my app. The first one contains products and each one of them is wrapped with a `CheckboxListTile` the checkbox value is a variable that's it's value is specified by checking if the product's id exist in a list called `selectedItemsList`, now the second screen is a cart screen that holds the selected products from the first screen, each `cartItem` is wrapped in a `Dismissible`, the `onDismissed` function removes the product from the cart and removes it's id from the `selectedItemsList` list.

What I want is to change the checkbox value after it has been removed from the cart when I press the back button and navigate back to the products screen from the cart screen.

**My goal in a more explained way:**

1. Products screen has 2 products (p1 and p2).
2. I select p1 and it's added to the cart and it's id is added to the `selectedItemsList`.
3. The value of the p1 checkbox is true (checked).
4. I navigate to cart screen and I remove the p1 from there.
5. p1 is now removed from cart and it's id is removed from `selectedItemsList`.
6. I press the back button and navigate back to products screen.
7. The p1 checkbox value should be false (not checked) because it's id is not in the `selectedItemsList`, but it's still true (checked).
8. I want to update (or actually rebuild) the products screen when I remove a product from cart in the cart screen.

I'm implementing the things mentioned above using he `bloc` pattern. I'm firing an event called `RemoveItemFromCart` from a `CartBloc`:

```
void _onDismissed({
    required BuildContext context,
    required int index,
  }) {
    BlocProvider.of<CartBloc>(context).add(
      RemoveItemFromCart(
        items: _cartItems,
        index: index,
        counts: _counts,
        filteredCounts: _filteredCounts,
        originalIndices: _originalIndices,
        filteredItems: _filteredCartItems,
        filtering: _filtering,
      ),
    );

    _firstTime = true;
  }
```

Then a state called `ItemRemovedFromCart` is yielded:

```
if (event is RemoveItemFromCart) {
      if (event.filtering &&
          event.originalIndices.isNotEmpty &&
          event.filteredCounts.isNotEmpty &&
          event.filteredItems.isNotEmpty) {
        int itemIndex = event.items.indexWhere(
          (item) => item.id == event.filteredItems[event.index].id,
        );
        productsRepository.unSelectProduct(
          id: event.items[itemIndex].id,
        );
        event.items.removeAt(itemIndex);
        event.counts.removeAt(itemIndex);
        event.filteredItems.removeAt(event.index);
        event.filteredCounts.removeAt(event.index);
        event.originalIndices.removeAt(event.index);
      } else {
        productsRepository.unSelectProduct(
          id: event.items[event.index].id,
        );
        event.items.removeAt(event.index);
        event.counts.removeAt(event.index);
      }

      yield ItemRemovedFromCart(
        items: event.items,
        counts: event.counts,
        filteredCounts: event.filteredCounts,
        filteredItems: event.filteredItems,
        originalIndices: event.originalIndices,
      );
    }
```

In the products screen I'm using a `BlocBuilder` to rebuild when this state is yielded (but for now I'm just trying to print a test string to see if it's working):

```
BlocBuilder<CartBloc, CartState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
   if (state is ItemRemovedFromCart) print('asd');
   return _buildProductsList(products, context);
  },
)
```

The print statement is not being executed, so how to listen to events from another screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what *is* the state, if it's not the one you expected?

Comment: no it is what I expect, the thing is that I want to update the products screen when this state is yielded by an event fired from the cart screen. @nvoigt

Comment: everything is working correctly, all I want is to update the products screen when ItemRemovedFromCart state is yielded. @nvoigt

Comment: and this state is only emitted from the cart screen, so my main problem is to listen to bloc events from another screen, and that's it @nvoigt

Comment: But both screens listen to the same BLoC, right? I will ask again... since you don't get the state you expect (printing asd), *what state do you get instead*?

Comment: oh sorry, now I got what you meant, you are right, the problem is that I'm getting another state, thank you so much for this, the state is CalculatedTotalPrice which is actually another state I defined

Comment: And... could that be correct? Is that the last state from the BLoC? How did that state came to be, can you debug your BLoC?

Comment: yes yes it's correct because I have a blocListener and I'm emitting a CalculatedTotalPrice  after I remove a product from the cart because I want to recalculate the total products' price, so yeah it's the last state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that bloc instances keep listening to events as long as they are not closed or disposed, so if we want to act upon events from another screen we simply add an event to the required bloc and that's it